# Get indices from Boolean array into lists

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, boolean

I have an array called TorF -True or False-, which is a Boolean array.  Say it is a 10 x 10 array with various Trues and Falses.  How do I get the indices of all the True elements?

On a 1D array, I see that np.where() works great.  And on my 10x10 array, I can use np.where(TorF[0]) and return the indices perfectly for the first row.  I can manually do np.where(TorF[1]) for the second row.

I would like to do it for all 10 rows or in a bigger array up to "N" rows.  The problem is that the number of True elements is different for each row. So the list of True elements indices might look like:

```
[0, 7, 9]  #the first, eighth, and tenth elements were True
[1, 4, 5, 8, 9]  #2nd, 5th, 6th, 9th, and 10th elements were True
[2, 6]
[0, 5, 7]
etc. up to ten lists or "N" lists
```

Since the list of indices are different lengths, I have problems.  How do I make a loop to get the list of True indices?  Or is there a better function to return this list?  Ideally I would like to have a variable called TrueList that holds these 10 subsets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use lists and a list comprehension inside another list comprehension:

```
>>> arr = np.random.randint(0, 2, (10, 10)).astype(bool)
>>> [[idx for idx, item in enumerate(subarr) if item] for subarr in arr.tolist()]
[[0, 5, 7, 8],
 [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9],
 [0, 3, 4, 9],
 [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9],
 [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7],
 [0, 7, 9],
 [0, 5, 8, 9],
 [1, 5, 7],
 [3, 6],
 [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]]
```

For small arrays using python iterations can even be faster than numpy functions like `np.where` so when you're dealing with 10x10 arrays the list comprehensions can be comparable in performance. But of course you can also use `np.where` in a list-comprehension:

```
>>> [np.where(subarr)[0] for subarr in arr]
[array([0, 5, 7, 8], dtype=int64),
 array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 3, 4, 9], dtype=int64),
 array([1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 7, 9], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 5, 8, 9], dtype=int64),
 array([1, 5, 7], dtype=int64),
 array([3, 6], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9], dtype=int64)]
```

Comment: I used the list comprehension method in my code, like you suggested, and it worked as stated.  I will study the syntax of that code more to fully understand and appreciate its logic.